# Backup Android phone directly to network location periodically

Tags: backup, images, cifs

I want to backup as much as possible from a rooted Android phone(`user-data, app-data`, etc) on a daily basis to a Synology NAS.

I've found this tutorial:

Automatic Nightly Backups for Your Android Device to Your Computer | Guysoft's Weblog
https://guysoft.wordpress.com/2012/11/01/android-nightly-backups/

The only problem remaining is that `Titanium Backup` performs the backup image on the phone, which is then copied to the NAS via `rsync`. I cannot afford this, since I don't have an SD card slot, nor much space left on the phone.

Any ideas on how to save directly to NAS(smb share) instead?

On the other hand, I was thinking at `adb`, as an alternative way to do a backup, but I haven't seen anyone installing it on a NAS. Besides installing, there should be some scripting involved, in order to detect the connection to the phone via `USB` or `WiFi`, and then the backup process.

Answer (score 0):

[SMBSync2](https://github.com/Sentaroh/SMBSync2) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).